# What is causing this Run-time Error 13 "Type Mis-Match"?

Tags: excel, runtime-error, autofill, vba

The code below increments a variable based upon which cells contain "Yes". It works just until I use auto-fill to set the value for any of the cells in F13:F59 to "Yes". When I type in the word "Yes" manually, the run-time error does not occur. However auto-fill, seems to be causing the issue.

```
Select Case (changedcell)
'Issues Mgmt
Case Range("F15"), Range("F19"), Range("F23"), Range("F27"), Range("F30"), Range("F39"), Range("F42"), Range("F45"), Range("F50"), Range("F53"), Range("F54") 'Issues
      If Range("F15").Value = "Yes" Then
        issues = issues + 1
      End If
      If Range("F19").Value = "Yes" Then
        issues = issues + 1
      End If
      If Range("F23").Value = "Yes" Then
        issues = issues + 1
      End If
      If Range("F27").Value = "Yes" Then
        issues = issues + 1
      End If
      If Range("F30").Value = "Yes" Then
        issues = issues + 1
      End If
      If Range("F39").Value = "Yes" Then
        issues = issues + 1
      End If
      If Range("F42").Value = "Yes" Then
        issues = issues + 1
      End If
      If Range("F45").Value = "Yes" Then
        issues = issues + 1
      End If
      If Range("F50").Value = "Yes" Then
        issues = issues + 1
      End If
      If Range("F53").Value = "Yes" Then
        issues = issues + 1
      End If
      If Range("F54").Value = "Yes" Then
        issues = issues + 1
      End If

      If issues > 1 Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        MsgBox "Issues Management has already been selected under another old solution category.", vbCritical, "Duplicate Use Case Selected"
        Range(target.Address).Value = ""
     End If
End Select
```

This first part of the code is where the error occurs. Any thoughts?

```
Case Range("F15"), Range("F19"), Range("F23"), Range("F27"), Range("F30"), Range("F39"), Range("F42"), Range("F45"), Range("F50"), Range("F53"), Range("F54") 'Issues
```

Comment: Is this part of a `Worksheet_Change` procedure?

Comment: Um... I dont use `Select Case` very much, but I've never seen it constructed like this before.. What is `(changedcell)`? Where is your `Case`? Isn't the point of writing a `Select Case` so that you _don't have to make a bunch of `If Then Else` statements?_

Comment: [An example of `Select Case`](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/select-case.html), what Microsoft has to say [about `Select Case`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cy37t14y.aspx)

Comment: Please check what autofill fills in the cells; explanation of the error [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa264979(v=vs.60).aspx) points to a wrong content in the cells.

Comment: Yeah, this is the exact opposite of what `Select Case` is for. I can't say for certain, but I suspect it's the Case statement itself that's throwing the error. It's expecting a Boolean expression and it's getting a series of ranges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim rIssues As Range
Dim rCll As Range
    Set rIssues = Range("F15,F19,F23,F27,F30,F39,F42,F45,F50,F53,F54")
    For Each rCll In rIssues
        If rCll.Value = "Yes" Then Issues = 1 + Issues
    Next

    If Issues > 1 Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        MsgBox "Issues Management has already been selected under another old solution category.", _
            vbCritical, "Duplicate Use Case Selected"
        Range(Target.Address).Value = ""
     End If
```

Suggest to read the following pages:

[For Each...Next Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg264596.aspx),

[Select Case Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg278665.aspx)

Comment: I would test if target intersects with the rIssues range, just to avoid looping when any cell is changed.  That is, I assume the OP has this in a WorkSheet_Change Event.  Also make sure EnableEvents is returned to True.

Comment: @ScottCraner I'm assuming this is part of a Worksheet_Change Event, also assuming the intersection and all other related parts are there as and working fine as the question affirms it fails only when using autofill in the case select, so it seems all other parts (we just don't know how what it is) are well covered. Thanks for the input...

Comment: EEM solved my issue! Also, thanks for the advice Scott. EnableEvents returns to true at the end of the sub.